# Getting city Name and country Name of the incoming call number?

Tags: android

Is there any ways to find out the city and country name of the incoming phone Number in android?

Comment: For getting country name of phone number, read my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/39424350/3336322

Comment: For getting country name of phone number, read my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/39424350/3336322

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to get city name .. for country name we can extract the country code from the incoming number to get the country name ...

Comment: Thankyou, for your reply, thats right i can access the country code but is there any way to fetch the city name may be the city where the number has been registered. something like city name for the home network city.