# Get the country of the incoming call

Tags: android, phone-number, telephonymanager

I am trying to create an app which recognizes the country of the incoming call, is there a way to do this? I was thinking to use the first four characters in the number to determine the country but this seems to be an ineffective approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve incoming call - [retrieve-incoming-calls-phone-number-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853220/retrieve-incoming-calls-phone-number-in-android)

Then use the country code - [getting-telephone-country-code-with-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402253/getting-telephone-country-code-with-android)

Then use country code to find country in your map.

All in all summing up (as mentioned here)--  [get-incoming-call-country-name-using-phone-number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773231/get-incoming-call-country-name-using-phone-number).

Comment: None of the links mentions how can I retrieve the incoming calls country or iso country code